# Running Loops in SQLPlus

Tags: bash, oracle, loops, plsql, sqlplus

I made a bash script that connects to a database by SQLPlus and runs a SQL Script which contains a For loop as below. But once running it, it stuck in the BEGIN of the loop as below. I tried to run it directly through SQLPlus and it is the same. So can anyone advise what is done wrong here.

```
BEGIN
  FOR l_counter IN 1..5
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( l_counter );
  END LOOP;
END
```

Result:

```
   BEGIN
  2  FOR l_counter IN 1..5
  3  LOOP
  4  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( l_counter );
  5  END LOOP;
  6  END;
  7
  8
```

Bash:

```
SPOOL $FILE

@/home/genesys/scripts/Counter.sql
SPOOL OFF
EXIT
EOF
```

Edit: This is the result I am getting after adding a slash at the end.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> BEGIN
  FOR l_counter IN 1..10
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( l_counter || ' finished ');
  END LOOP;
END;/  2    3    4    5    6
  7
  8
  9
 10
```

Comment: add a slash at the end, after the last semi-colon, and add `set serveroutput on` to the beginning.

Comment: [edit] your question and post the contents of the _bash_ script. I assume that you are calling `get "sql script"` rather than `start "sql script"`

Comment: SQL\*Plus needs to terminate PL/SQL blocks with a slash, otherwise it doesn't know where the end of the code is.

Comment: @Barbaros?zhan I did that and still doesn't work and got no output. 
    
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> BEGIN
  FOR l_counter IN 1..10
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( l_counter || ' finished ');
  END LOOP;
END;/  2    3    4    5    6
  7
  8
  9
 10

Comment: @Abra I updated the question but the case is that it happens also when connecting directly by SQLPlus.

Comment: a slash must be on the new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefer using one of the following two methods in order to put the results of the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` command into a file

1. By using `.sql` file

```
$ cd /home/genesys/scripts
$ sqlplus /nolog
SQL> conn un/pwd
SQL> @Counter.sql
```

where `Counter.sql` file has the following content :

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SPOOL output2.txt
BEGIN
FOR l_counter IN 1..10
 LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_counter || ' finished ');
 END LOOP; 
END;
/
SPOOL OFF
```

2. By Creating a `.sh`(`Counter.sh`) file :

```
record=`sqlplus -S /nolog << EOF
conn hr/hr
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SPOOL output.txt
BEGIN
 FOR l_counter IN 1..10
 LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_counter || ' finished ');
 END LOOP; 
END;
/
SPOOL OFF
EOF`
```

call from the command prompt where you created the file

```
$ cd /home/genesys/scripts
$ . Counter.sh
```

Comment: @AhmedZein you're welcome bro, nice to help