# Replicate the log file in oracle plsql package and save it with different name

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to create the log file which is same as the existing one in oracle plsql package . I dont want to replicate the same code for different log file.Is there any way i can copy the existing log file in plsql package and use that log file to show into control-m output.

Comment: PL/SQL doesn't really do file system level commands. Why must you do this with PL/SQL?

Comment: What log file?  No one here knows what/which "the logfile" you are referring to.  What is "control-m output"?

Comment: you can create a bash script in order to call sqlplus. [this little example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66301579/running-loops-in-sqlplus/66338552#66338552) might help.

Comment: @pmdba, because - I presume - when the only tool you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.

Comment: You need to give more information,.what is "create the log file"? can you copy the package in the question? what i "control-m"?